# How can I prevent my reviewer name from converting to “Author” after saving a Microsoft Word document on Mac's MS Word 2011?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, version-control, microsoft-word-2011

Upon insertion of a comment or revision change Microsoft Word documents correctly reflects my User Name as the reviewer. However, after I save the document, all of my comments and revisions are converted to "Author."

I saw this thread:
[Prevent reviewer name from converting to "Author" after saving a Word document](https://superuser.com/questions/191232/how-can-i-prevent-my-reviewer-name-from-converting-to-author-after-saving-a-mi)

It explains how to solve it on MS Word for Windows, but the menus referred there do not exist on the Mac version. So, how can I prevent the removal personal information from the file properties on save?